# Manifolds and actions: a counterexample

Tags: manifolds

Let $X$ be an $m$-dimensional simply connected manifold that is also a G-space. If the action is properly discontinuous, is $X/G$ necessarily a manifold?

Do you have a hint for this one?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't suppose that the action is free then $X/G$ may not be a manifold. For example, $\mathbb{R}/\{\pm 1\}=\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ (action by multiplication). To get something that is not even a manifold with boundary, take e.g. $Y=\mathbb{R^3}/\{\pm 1\}$ (to prove it, notice e.g. that the relative homology $H_2(Y,Y-\{0\})\cong H_1(\mathbb{RP}^2)$ is non-trivial, or use the local fundamental group of $Y-{0}$).

(if the action is free and properly discontinuous then $X/G$ is certainly a manifold)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a precise result:

**Theorem**
Let a Lie group $G$ act smoothly, freely and  properly on the Hausdorff manifold $X$. Then the quotient topological space $X/G$ is Hausdorff and admits of a differential structure such that the quotient map $X\to X/G$ is a smooth submersion.

**Remarks**
1) Simple connectedness of $X$ is irrelevant.

2) This is quite a difficult theorem very well treated  in Chapter 9 of John M. Lee's [book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=john+lee+smooth&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=_Bl0T9qMOsKF4gTI4Ky9Dg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=john%20lee%20smooth&f=false).

3) If $G$ is compact, properness of a  smooth free action is automatic.

4) The smooth map  $\pi: X\to X/G$ is a categorical quotient in the sense that, for any differential manifold $Y$, composition with $\pi$ yields a bijection 
$$\mathcal C^\infty (X/G,Y)\stackrel {\cong}{\to} \mathcal C^\infty_G (X,Y)$$
where  $\mathcal C^\infty_G (X,Y)$ denotes $G$-equivariant smooth maps.